# remove line inside the circle div

Tags: html, css

i have four circle in row in each circle one icon exist in the middle of the circle. i draw a red line using pseudo classes in css. this red line cross circle in the middle. i just want that this red line not show inside the circle but show  out side the circle.i think a lot but cant find any solution's

```css
#services .block .icon-block {
    border: 4px solid yellow;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#services .block .icon-block a {
    font-size: 25px;
}
#services .block .upper-block::before{
    border: 2px solid red;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head
<body>
<section id="services">
    <div class="container block">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3 upper-block">
                <div class="icon-block">
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cloud" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 upper-block">
                <div class="icon-block">
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cloud" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 upper-block">
                <div class="icon-block">
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cloud" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 upper-block">
                <div class="icon-block">
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cloud" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<!-- end (services) --> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these two settings:

```
#services .block .icon-block {
    background: #fff;
}
#services .block .upper-block::before{
    z-index: -1;
}
```

They move the red line to the background (using a negative `z-index` value) and make the circle areas non-transparent (i.e. covering the red line )

```css
#services .block .icon-block {
    border: 4px solid yellow;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin:0 auto;
    background: #fff;
}
#services .block .icon-block a {
    font-size: 25px;
}
#services .block .upper-block::before{
    border: 2px solid red;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head
<body>
<section id="services">
    <div class="container block">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3 upper-block">
                <div class="icon-block">
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cloud" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 upper-block">
                <div class="icon-block">
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cloud" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 upper-block">
                <div class="icon-block">
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cloud" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 upper-block">
                <div class="icon-block">
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cloud" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<!-- end (services) --> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the z-index of the line and add a white background to the circle. See below.

```css
#services .block .icon-block {
    border: 4px solid yellow;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color: white;
}
#services .block .icon-block a {
    font-size: 25px;
}
#services .block .upper-block::before{
    border: 2px solid red;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -99;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head
<body>
<section id="services">
    <div class="container block">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3 upper-block">
                <div class="icon-block">
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cloud" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 upper-block">
                <div class="icon-block">
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cloud" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 upper-block">
                <div class="icon-block">
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cloud" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 upper-block">
                <div class="icon-block">
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cloud" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<!-- end (services) --> 
</body> 
</html>
```